# Getting a nice <li>

Tags: php, html, css, html-lists

I want the data that I get out of the Database so look the same way as the `<li>` does but then with the output from the database too show.

[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMU3W.png) as you can see it puts the lines under it with the data out of the database and I want this to be both like the `<li>'s`

```
<div class="row content">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
         <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#section2">Friends</a></li>
         <li><a href="#section3">Family</a></li>
         <li><a href="#section3">Photos</a></li>
         <?php
         $toppics = $app->get_topics();
         foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
         echo $topic['onderwerp'] . '<br />';
         }
         ?>
   </ul><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Stupid question, but have you actually tried `echo '<li>'.$topic['onderwerp'] . '</li>';`?

Comment: Then echo the data in an `<li> ... </li>` pair like the previous lines

Comment: but how do I get it that it enters after each "onderwerp" there is so after every record it needs to put the new "onderwerp" on a different line

Comment: every-one talking but no one closing the question as off-topic

Comment: @AlivetoDie: That's because it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap you output in `<li>` too:

```
foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
     echo '<li>' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</li>';
}

// Each `onderwerp` in it's own <ul>
// BUT previous <ul> must be closed.
foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
     echo '<ul><li>' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</li></ul>';
}

// dynamic href attribute
$i = 4;
foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
     echo '<li><a href="#section' . $i++ . '">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with a bit of low hanging fruit now and again :)

Comment: And what if I want to show each "onderwerp" on a different line so its not all in 1 `<li>` but in diffent onces

Comment: Each `onderwerp` is in it's own `li`.

Comment: Oopppsss! Starting to look like the infamous 'Rabbit hole' type question. :) The answer that has to keep on giving :) :)

Comment: @youarewelkommmornot: That's literally what this does. Give it a try. And perhaps review what `foreach` does..

Comment: @u_mulder i need got it now like this `foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
                                                echo '<li><a href="#section4">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a></li>';
                                            }` but now both of the buttons are set at `#section4` and I want to be abble to link both records on a different way, so if I click the one "onderwerp" i need to get it to link to somewhere else then the other

Comment: @youarewelkommmornot That is a different question.

Comment: @MrLister well because he answered this one he might now the other one too?

Comment: Next time describe your problem __more carefully__.

Comment: I sure will @u_mulder and thanks for the help, I still have a little question :# I want it that if you click on it it will lead you to a ahref (website) where you can see other things out of the database any tips? tricks?

Comment: Tips for what? You know how links work? You add an address to `href` and clicking on it takes you to this address. What else do you need?

Comment: This is obvoiusly __another question__. This is not a chat here.

Comment: @u_mulder changed the question

Comment: __NEVER__ change the question. Ask __another one__. If I answered to one question and you changed it to completely different - how my answer can be of any help to others?

Comment: Well i thought because if had 5 downvotes this was a dumb question so I changed it! Next time ill ask an other one! okay? @u_mulder

Comment: I rollbacked your question. Stop writing comments and go ask a __new  one__.

Comment: @u_mulder I would!!! but Because of the downvotes I cant do another question for 5 days ... So how do I do that then? making a new account?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited. Here what you should start with.